# Google app engine + objectify gives 503 Service Unavailable error when starting server

Tags: android, google-app-engine, android-studio, gradle, objectify

I am developing an android application with a Google App Engine Java Endpoints Module as backend, and using the Objectify framework to communicate with the datastore. I have two entities: Parent and Child, as well as their the auto generated Cloud Endpoints classes. Sometimes when I start the local server I get the following error:

> Information:Gradle: Executing tasks: [:api:assemble]
>   Information:Compilation completed with 1 error and 0 warnings in 40 sec
>   Information:1 error
>   Information:0 warnings
>
> Error:Gradle: Execution failed for task ':api:appengineEndpointsGetDiscoveryDocs'.
>
> There was an error running endpoints command get-discovery-doc: 503 Service Unavailable
>       {
>       "error": {
>        "errors": [
>         {
>         "domain": "global",
>         "reason": "backendError",
>         "message": "Backend Error"
>        }
>        ],
>        "code": 503,
>        "message": "Backend Error"
>       }
>       }

This error message happens randomly when starting the server. Sometimes it starts normally, but other times I have to clean the project and restart the server 2-3 times before the server will run. The error message varies slightly. Sometimes it it will generate the same 503, but failing to get the client libraries instead.

> Error:Gradle: Execution failed for task ':api:appengineEndpointsGetClientLibs'.

I have no idea why this happens, and was wondering if anyone has any expereince with this.

I have added both endpoints to the web.xml-file as following:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>SystemServiceServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.google.api.server.spi.SystemServiceServlet
</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>services</param-name>
        <param-value>
            com.example.backend.ParentEndpoint,
            com.example.backend.ChildEndpoint
        </param-value>
    </init-param>
</servlet>
```

### Parent Entity

```
@Entity
public class Parent {
    @Id
    Long id;
    String name;
    Ref<Child> child;

    public Parent(){}

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public Child getChild() {
        return child.get();
    }

    public void setChild(Child child) {
        this.child = Ref.create(child);
    }
}
```

### Child Entity

```
@Entity
public class Child {
     @Id
     Long id;
     String name;

     public Child(){}

     public Long getId() {
        return id;
     }

     public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
     }

     public String getName() {
        return name;
     }

     public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
     }
}
```

Comment: The problem is not in your entities but in your endpoints, please include the code for those.

Comment: It seems as though the problem was on google's side. It works fine again now.

Comment: How did you make it work? I get the same error! @jirungaray

Comment: I have no idea what fixed this issue. As I wrote in a previous comment, it seemed as though the problem was at Google's side. Suddenly it just started working again...